# UITableView and UIPickerView interaction issues

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, uipickerview

I have a UITableView consisting of three rows - each row is a data field in a settings screen. When the user clicks a row, I have a `UIPickerView` appear for them to select a value. I am using the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` - the left side is the name of the data field, and the right side (`detailTextLabel`) should be the value selected from the picker.

I created a targetCell ivar to hold the selected cell. In my picker, I use the below code in the `didSelectRow` method:

```
    self.targetCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"TEST";
```

Which works, however I have several presentational issues. The first was that the detailTextLabel text was white (although API says it should be blue??!?) I fixed this with:

```
    self.targetCell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

However, the text does not appear in the cell until I click the cell or another cell. So I tried adding a 
    `[self.tableView reloadData];`
Which does the trick of refreshing the cell and getting the label text to appear, but also removes the blue highlighting which I want to maintain.

If you could look over this code and let me know the easiest way to get the below results when selecting a value on the picker:

- cell `detailTextLabel.text` immediately updates to the selected
  value in black color
- the blue highlight on the active cell is maintained

Thanks!

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
    // Handle the selection 
    self.targetCell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.targetCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"TEST";
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**Edited to add final code soluton:**

Thanks to chown for the answer - my final working code is:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
    // Handle the selection 
    self.targetCell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.targetCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"TEST";
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:path.row inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Comment: Just a note, but setting the text in a table cell doesn't give you any kind of persistence - you would normally update whatever you are using as your table data source, then call reloadData.

Comment: +1 @jrturton - in this case the values are saved into nsuserdefaults when the user exits the screen, so persistence is accounted for - but that's a good point to keep in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
    // Handle the selection 
    self.targetCell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.targetCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"TEST";
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSIndexPath *ip = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    // assuming self is the tableViews delegate.  Optional
    [self tableView:tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:ip];

    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableScrollPositionTop];

    // assuming self is the tableViews delegate.  Optional
    [self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:ip];
}
```

Comment: The mechanics of this work, but row in indexPathForRow == the pickerView's selected row, not the targetCell's row #... i could store the targetCell's indexPath.row in another ivar, but there must be an easier way? Feel like i'm missing something really simple here...

Comment: In that case, if you want to keep the currently selected row, change to this: `NSIndexPath *ip = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow;` or see my updated answer.

Comment: cool, the NSIndexPath *ip = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; did it for me....I'm updating my question with the final code I used...although I have to ask - is there a simpler way?

Comment: Not really, i use this same method in several places of my code as well.  If i do find a better way I'll update here though.  I do wish reloading the table didnt remove the cell highlighting :/